# Samsung LCD 214T gets stuck in power saving mode

Tags: display, power-management, lcd, blank-screen

I've had this monitor (Samsung 214T)  for more than 5 years, and had to replace the capacitors  a couple years ago.  It still works beautifully, but it's always had a similar problem that when I switched source to a different computer you would have to turn off the monitor power and restart it to see anything.  Well, I always thought it was the 50 ft VGA cable that I used, but now I wonder.  Anyway, the current problem is that when the computer turns the monitor blank in power saving, and I wait more than an hour to touch the mouse or keyboard, it doesn't turn back on.  If it's off only ten or twenty minutes it usually comes back on but once in a while no. Turning off the power and and unplugging the data cable and waiting a bit has always fixed the problem, but sometimes it takes two tries.

I've switched to a standard DVI cable and a different computer and the problem persists.  I've used the same video card on the new computer, but when I plug in a different monitor at the time it's blank and I've unplugged and plugged in the problem monitor data cable with no result, the picture shows up right away on the other monitor. The other monitor has to use a VGA/DVI adapter.

I'm at my wits end, and would be grateful for any help or comments.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be caused by improperly installed video drivers.  Avast free antivirus had to be disabled.  Nvidia drivers were reinstalled in Safe Mode, and the problems went away.